# Admin side modification django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-2.0

I have this class In which when I submit a name it goes to admin and only admin can approve this. I want that when admin approve a email automatically should be sent to user.

```
  class myab(models.Model):
        generic_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        is_approved = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
```

I only wanted to know how to trigger email code . I have everything else just wanted to understand how to trigger that function when Admin will approve this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a listener function to the [post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) and use a `if` to check if the instance was approved; read the [signal docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) for a better understanding.

The signal receiver could look similar to this:

```
from django.core import mail
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel


@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

    if instance.is_approved:
        mail.send_mail(...)
```

Highlighting [this section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver):

> **Where should this code live?**
>
> [...] signal handling [...] code can live
>   anywhere you like, although it’s recommended to avoid the
>   application’s root module and its models module [...]
>
> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals
>   submodule of the application they relate to [...]

Comment: @gamer I expanded my answer; signals should be in its own file (or submodule) called `signals.py`.

Comment: thanks for reply . can we use a function same like this on deletion of instance aswell ?

Comment: @gamer yes, in that case you would listen for the [`pre_delete` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-delete) (or post_delete)

Comment: Thanks bro so much <3 . I have one more issue and I posted question as well. I want to modify admin side . like in city dropdown I want city names from api in admin side. is it possible ?

Comment: Hi I am not getting signal :(  I saw in debuger and its not going into signals.py file where this code is pasted

Comment: @gamer Which signal are you listening for? Are you using the models `.save()` method?

Comment: yes for save . exact same which is written in code. but when I use in model.py its working